# Best way to edit (add/remove) rows in a 0 to many child table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF 6.1 Code First and MVC 5.

I have a parent table with 0 to many children in a child table.

Below are my Parent / Child models my View Models, and the code in a controller that edits.

What I have below is working to make sure it removes the rows from the child table that were removed, adds new ones, and leaves the existing rows that weren't changed alone.

However, I'm wondering if there is a better, less complex way to take care of the situation.

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

}

public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ChildrenViewModel Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildrenViewModel 
{
    public int[] SelectedValues { get; set; } // The Selected Values
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; } // Items in the List Box
}

if (parentViewModel.Children == null)
{
    // If the collection in the parent view model is null, then clear the collection in the parent and save
    parent.Children.Clear();
}
else
{
    // add new items if it exists in the view model but isnt already in the database
        foreach (int childId in parentViewModel.Children.SelectedValues)
        {
            if (!parent.Children.Any(f => f.ChildId == childId))
            {
                offense.Children.Add(new Child{ ChildId = childId });
            }
        }

        // delete children from the parent that are no longer present in the view model collection

        IList<Child> deleteList = new List<Child>();
        foreach (Child child in parent.Children)
        {
            if (!parentViewModel.Children.SelectedValues.Contains(child.ChildId))
            {
                deleteList.Add(child);
            }
        }

        foreach (Child child in deleteList)
        {
            parent.Children.Remove(child);
        }
    }
db.Save()
```

Comment: There may be a "Tryhard" solution for this but I think this looks good. It's how I would do it. Is this causing performance issues for you?

Comment: No it isn't causing a performance issue. I am new to entity framework and MVC and wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something silly.

Thank you.